# Mysql INNER JOIN query with multiple AND condition in same table

Tags: mysql, database

[Inner join query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1uHc.png)
I have 2 table `user_info` and `user_role_info`. I want to select those user who are in role_id 1 and also at least 1 of the role_id 2 to 4.

What I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `user_info` a 
INNER JOIN `user_role_info` r ON r.`user_id` = a.`user_id`
WHERE  r.`role_id`= 1 AND r.`role_id` BETWEEN 2 AND 7 GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

From the picture user_id 1 & 2 should be the correct result & user_id 4 should not in the result.
But this query doesn't provide me the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You should be asserting the role IDs in the `HAVING` clause.  Something like the following should work:

```sql
SELECT a.user_id
FROM user_info a 
INNER JOIN user_role_info r
    ON r.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY a.user_id
HAVING SUM(r.role_id = 1) > 0 AND
       SUM(r.role_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) > 0;
```